# Gmail smtp authentication error

Tags: python, smtp, gmail

Ok so I am trying to authenticate a password with gmail smtp.
I am trying to run code that tells me when the password is correct. Basicly the server gives me an authentication error while trying to connect with true creditionals:
[http://m.imgur.com/k3fIk5k](https://m.imgur.com/k3fIk5k)
When it is wrong creditionals, it gives a different error:
[http://m.imgur.com/FiU1n1S](https://m.imgur.com/FiU1n1S)
I am using Python smtplib to do this. Can I specify the error code inside the auth error?
Example:

```
try:
    smtpserver.login("mygmail","mypassword")
except smtplib.SMTPAuthenicationError(-1):
    print "password: %s" %s
```

In the photo you can see the error contains -1 for a correct login, and a 534 for an incorrect login, can I detect that in "except"?

Comment: You might try doing something like `except Exception as e:`, and then you have the variable e which is the exception message.  You can then parse the exception message and do different things depending on what it says.  There may be a better way to do things, but this is what first came to mind.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you error number which you can use to recognize problem

```
except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError as ex:
    print ex.args[0]
```